# Set value of input element on specific class of parent element

Tags: jquery, magento

I want to set values to a hidden input field, depending on the classes added to the parent element on document.ready. I have the following PHP and jQuery code in my files:

```
<?php
foreach($attributeOptions as $value) { ?>
    <div id="js-button" class="jarsettings-button <?php checkIfSelected($value['value'], $_settings) ?>">
        <?= $value['label']; ?>
        <input type="hidden" value="" id="cb-<?= $value['value']; ?>" name="js-cb" />
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
```

What happens here is that the script checks in a former declared function wheter the class that has to been added to the element trought **checkIfSelected()** is either **active** or **inactive**. It will be "active" if the database tells us that this specific element has to be active on page load, and if not vice versa.

My jQuery looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function($){

            if( jQuery('#js-button').hasClass('active') ) {
                jQuery(this).find('input').val('1');
            } else if ( jQuery('#js-button').hasClass('inactive') ){
                        jQuery(this).find('input').val('0');
            }

        jQuery('.jarsettings-button').click(function(){             
            jQuery(this).fadeToggle(150).toggleClass('active');
            jQuery(this).fadeToggle(150).toggleClass('inactive');

            if( jQuery(this).hasClass('active') ){
                jQuery(this).find('input').val('1');
            } else if ( jQuery(this).hasClass('inactive') ){
                jQuery(this).find('input').val('0');
            }   
        })
    })      
</script>
```

I want the value of each field either 0 (on former declared inactive class) or 1 (if active class). The check itself works if you click on a element, but I still get only value="1" for all input fields, nevertheless which class has been added. I first tried the class id in jQuery (.jarsetings-button), but it hasn't worked yet. I changed it to the ID, still now functional detection of the value.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You surely want to use the complete `fadeToggle()` callback and not duplicating

Comment: Sorry, I do not understand, could you clarify your comment a little for me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with following code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
        jQuery('.jarsettings-button').each(function(){
            var parent = jQuery(this);
            if(  parent.hasClass('active')) {
                jQuery(parent).find('input').val('1');
            } else if ( parent.hasClass('inactive') ){
                jQuery(parent).find('input').val('0');
            }
        });


    jQuery('.jarsettings-button').click(function(){             
        jQuery(this).fadeToggle(150).toggleClass('active');
        jQuery(this).fadeToggle(150).toggleClass('inactive');

        if( jQuery(this).hasClass('active') ){
            jQuery(this).find('input').val('1');
        } else if ( jQuery(this).hasClass('inactive') ){
            jQuery(this).find('input').val('0');
        }   
    })
})
```

There was a miss in first `if...else` part

In case of `click` part; `this` reference points to the element on which click action has been performed and hence that part is correct.

Comment: Close one! Right now, all "active"-Elements get the value="1", but all inactive elements get NO value for their respective input. Any thoughts on this? Thanks so far. :*

Comment: Yes, right now I assign the same Id to all divs, since I cannot get out of the foreach loop where the unqiue IDs could be generated. :/

Comment: If you change **var parent = this;** to **var parent = jQuery(this);** I can mark your answer as the correct one. :)

Comment: Good catch...awesome.Thanks...`:)`!

Answer (score 1):

The above code will only work for **first element** since you are duplicating the `ids` in `foreach`. So I would say, better, remove that `id` *[or find anyway to dynamically create unique ids]* and refer element using `class` on `document.ready` as below:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
   jQuery('.jarsettings-button').each(function(){
         //use ternary operation
         var val=jQuery(this).hasClass('active')?1:0;
         jQuery(this).find('input').val(val);

   });
  //click event here
});
```

Comment: Thank you for your input, very much appreciated! :) From what I see (and can compare) its most likely the same code as above, just with another formatting. I have NOT tested your code, but it should work - as far as I can judge.

Comment: This is efficient way you can achieve it, instead of multiple `if-else`. That's it.. :) Helps when you think of application performance..

Comment: I will keep that in my mind! Never used "each" so far, simply because I did not know that it even existed. Clarifies a lot why my former jQuery codes hasn't worked as intended. u_u

Comment: No probs.. Happy to help.. Happy coding.. :)